# Windows 7 UAC warning message causes

Tags: windows-7, uac

We've started testing an application on Windows 7. We first got the "unknown provider" message.  We signed the application and now get a message:

> Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to your computer?

None of these messages were generated in Vista.  I know UAC is enhanced in Win 7.  It has been difficult to find out what's actually causing these messages.

I've searched the web and not come up with a good list of what generates this second message.  Does anyone have such a list?  Also, does anyone know if this message is generated when the application is trying to access the system in an unapproved way or is the flag somehow compiled into the application?

Comment: Good question. Also, does anyone know why Winamp keeps trying to "make changes to my computer"? ;)

Comment: @Thomas: Probably that's Winamp's auto-update?

Comment: @DFP: Does this message come already at startup? It would help to know what your application is doing right before the message pops up.

Comment: Isn't that just a standard UAC prompt?  Either your application is manifested to ask for administrative privileges or it is detected by the UAC installer heuristics.

Comment: Do you have a manifest on your app? If you don't know, what version of Visual Studio did you build it with? What is the name of your application? (whatever.exe)

Comment: Please provide more details: when does the prompt appear?

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem once, i did the following, either one of them should do it:

-> Changing rights of the folder where application is installed solved the problem, just give full access to that folder.

-> [More of a WORKAROUND] Running the application as administrator and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add an assembly manifest to your application stating `requestedExecutionLevel=asInvoker`.

That will disable the UAC prompts.